# How to use class properties in a predicate that's a property of a class?

Tags: c#

My class has the following structure (shrunk an omitted irrelevant parts):

```cs
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private T svalue;
    private Predicate<T> spredicate;

    private void Update(T nvalue)
    {
        if(spredicate(nvalue))
            svalue = nvalue;
    }

    public MyClass(Predicate<T> condition){
        spredicate = condition;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return svalue; }
        set { Update(value); }
    }
}
```

Basically, it stores a value, and only allows changing it if the new value fits a predicate.

I want the following code to work:

```cs
var myvar = new MyClass<int>(x => Math.Abs(x - myvar.Value < 10));
```

However, this doesn't compile because "I'm using a local variable which value wasn't set yet".

In the end, I want to be able to reference a public class property in that predicate. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a weird interaction for a consumer of your code:  "I just set the value, why is it still showing the old value!?!?"

Comment: Try: `MyClass<int> myvar = null; myvar = new MyClass<int>(x => Math.Abs(x - myvar.Value) < 10);` Note that if you afterwards change which object `myvar` refers to, you're changing the predicate.

Comment: If you want the predicate to reference the properties of any particular instance of any particular class, either make the instance, or a property value from the instance, a parameter to the predicate, or use a delegate as the predicate.

Comment: @KennethK. Yeah it's not very responsive. My program updates the value every ~50 ms based on information it takes from the screen, and then immediately uses it, so this is my way of dealing with misdetection-caused spikes.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks, this works for me!

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Given that the real solution is so simple, it doesn't seem wise to suggest using such a fragile side-effect instead.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Admittedly it does read like spaghetti code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I agree, but if he needs to pass in 2 parameters, it's no longer a `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen True. If there were a hard requirement to use `Predicate<T>`, he'd have to do something like that. Fortunately that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your predicate to have a reference to a class instance, pass it in:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private T svalue;
    private Func<MyClass<T>, T, bool> spredicate;

    private void Update(T nvalue)
    {
        if (spredicate(this, svalue))
            svalue = nvalue;
    }

    public MyClass(Func<MyClass<T>, T, bool> condition)
    {
        spredicate = condition;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return svalue; }
        set { Update(value); }
    }

    public static void Example()
    {
        var myvar = new MyClass<int>((self, newval) => Math.Abs(newval - self.svalue) < 10);
    }
}
```

We could instead give the predicate a second `T` parameter instead of `MyClass<T>`, but then there would be confusion about which parameter is the old value and which is the new one.